# if $f$ is continuous y $g$ is strictly increasing, then $\lim_{n -> \infty}(\int_{a}^{b}|f|^{n}dg)^{1/n} = \left \| f \right \|_{a,b}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Hi the problem is the following:

If $f$ : [a,b]$\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous y $g$ : [a,b]$\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is strictly increasing, then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f|^{n}\mathrm{d}g\right)^{1/n} = \left \| f \right \|_{a,b}$$

My steps:

What I have been trying is to use the fact that it is continuous for as long as its domain is closed, the function is bounded there, the $f$, I think that this integral would be bounded by an $M$ multiplied by $(a-b)^{1/n}$ and that at infinity it tends to only $M$, I can consider $M$ as the maximum of $f$ in $(a,b)$, but I'm not sure if my reasoning is valid since since it is a Stieltjes integral I think it is necessary to use the I know that $g$ is increasing but I don't know how to use it. Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: To see why you need to use that $g$ is strictly increasing, check whether it's true when $g=0$.

Comment: Have you seen the proof of this fact when $g(x)=x$, giving us the plain Riemann [or Lebesgue] integral?

Comment: @Brian Moehring Yes, I have seen it for the case of g(x) = x but I do not see how I can generalize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as $g$ is increasing, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of continuous functions has many of the same properties as the plain Riemann integral, just with some minor changes.

Specifically, when $g : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing, $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $m \leq f(x) \leq M$ for every $x\in [a,b]$, we have
$$m(g(b)-g(a)) = \int_a^b m\, \mathrm{d}g \leq \int_a^b f\, \mathrm{d}g \leq \int_a^b M\, \mathrm{d}g = M(g(b)-g(a))$$
and for any $c \in [a,b]$,
$$\int_a^b f\,\mathrm{d}g = \int_a^c f\,\mathrm{d}g + \int_c^b f\,\mathrm{d}g.$$
That's all we need to know about the Riemann-Stieltjes integral to show this result.

---

For the rest of the argument, let $M=\|f\|_{a,b} \geq 0$.

For any $n$, the function $|f|^n : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $0 \leq |f|^n \leq M^n$, so by the first fact above,
$$0 \leq \int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g \leq M^n(g(b)-g(a))$$
so that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g\right)^{1/n} \leq M\cdot \limsup_{n\to\infty}\,(g(b)-g(a))^{1/n}$$

Here, we find the first time we need to know $g$ is *strictly increasing*, so that $g(b)-g(a) > 0$, not just $\geq 0$, in order to conclude $\limsup_{n\to\infty} (g(b)-g(a))^{1/n} = 1$.  That is, this shows
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g\right)^{1/n} \leq M.$$

To turn our attention to the lower bound, we now let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary.  Since $|f|$ is continuous, there is some $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $|f|(x_0) = M$. Again by continuity, this shows there is some $x_1 \in (a,b)$ such that $|f|(x_1) \geq M-\frac\varepsilon2$, and one final application of continuity, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $a < x_1-\delta < x_1+\delta < b$ and $x \in [x_1-\delta, x_1+\delta]$ implies $|f|(x) \geq M-\varepsilon$.

To summarize the above and for ease of writing, define $c := x_1-\delta$, $d := x_1+\delta$, so that $a<c<d<b$ and $x\in [c,d]$ implies $|f|^n(x) \geq \max(M-\varepsilon, 0)^n$.

Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g
 &= \int_a^c |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g + \int_c^d |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g + \int_d^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g \\
 &\geq 0\cdot(g(c)-g(a)) + \max(M-\varepsilon, 0)^n\cdot ((g(d)-g(c)) + 0 \cdot (g(b)-g(d)) \\
 &= \max(M-\varepsilon, 0)^n\cdot ((g(d)-g(c)) \\
 &\geq 0
\end{align*}$$
so that $$\left(\int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g\right)^{1/n} \geq \max(M-\varepsilon, 0) \cdot ((g(d)-g(c))^{1/n}$$
and $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g\right)^{1/n} \geq \max(M-\varepsilon, 0) \cdot \liminf_{n\to\infty} ((g(d)-g(c))^{1/n} = \max(M-\varepsilon, 0)$$
where we've once again used the assumption that $g$ is *strictly increasing*.

Let $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ to see $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g\right)^{1/n} \geq M$$

---

Finally, since $$M \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g\right)^{1/n} \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g\right)^{1/n} \leq M,$$
we conclude that the limit exists and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_a^b |f|^n\,\mathrm{d}g\right)^{1/n} = M = \|f\|_{a,b}$$

Comment: Thank you so much :3